# Array of string in C: OK within a function, full of garbage in main()

Tags: c, arrays, string, garbage

An array of strings is created in main and passed to a function. This function reads strings from a file and stores every line of the file in a different row of the array. Then finishes and returns to main. If I printf the contents of array[i] within the function, the text displayed in the screen is OK. If I do the same after returning to main(), printf writes only garbage. Why is main() not accessing the contents of the memory positions of the array?

```
void createlist(char* file, char **mylist) {

    FILE* stream;
    char name[40];
    int i = 0;

    stream = fopen(file, "r");      

    while (fgets(name, sizeof(name), stream) != NULL) { 

        mylist[i] = name;
        printf(mylist[i]);   // <------------------------This works OK! 
        i++;
    }
    fclose(stream);
}

void main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    char list[3000][40]; 
    int i = 0;
    resetchararray(list, 3000);

    createlist("file", list);   

    for (i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
        printf(list[i]);    // <---------------------This writes garbage
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm actually surprised that the compiler will allow the code, considering that you pass incompatible types for the `list` argument to the function.

Comment: shouldn't you pass `&list` ?

Comment: Did you get any compiler warnings?

Comment: @Shark no that's wrong too. The parameter should be `char mylist[3000][40]` or `char mylist[][40]`.

Comment: Hi all, there are no compiler warnings, it's very strange. Finally I corrected what @Jabberwocky and Vorac said and it works perfect. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`name` is a local variable in your function. It disappears after the function ends and leaves only garbage behind. To achieve what you are trying, use `strcpy()`, instead of `mylist[i] = name;`.

What is happening currently:

1. `createlist("file", list);` pass `list` by value **@Shark** warns!
2. `mylist[i] = name;` makes `mylist[i]` hold the address of a local variable!
3. `createlist()` terminates, having changed only a local copy of `list` (see point 1)

Comment: That's only half of the story, `strcpy()`  won't compile unless the type of the `mylist` parameter is corrected.

Comment: Strangely, it compiles OK "as is" (I'm using MS Visual Studio, which I know could be quite weird). @Vorac, it works OK after changing what you said and correcting the type as pointed by Jabberwocky. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @CarpoCrates you should upvote and/or accept the answer

Comment: You can't pass arrays by value as arguments to functions -- the compiler converts to a pointer behind your back, which is confusing.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Sorry, I'm a newbie here. Didn't know about that. I've already accepted the solution. Thanks for advising.

Answer (score 0):

Compiling your code gives the warning:

```
program.c:26:24: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘createlist’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     createlist("file", list);   
                    ^
program.c:3:6: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[40]’
 void createlist(char* file, char **mylist) {
```

which tells you what one of the problems you have is -- the pointer you are passing to `createlist` is the wrong type.  As declared, createlist expects an array of pointers, but you're trying to pass in an array of arrays.  There are other problems, such as storing the address of a local variable in your pointer array -- which will be invalid after the function returns.

Comment: Thank you, I finally corrected the code and it works fine.